# How to display String of records row by row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

when I execute my select Query I'm getting the Results like below:

Note:I have used Group_ConCat() function for EmpId and Absent_dates columns because the columns are returning multiple values from other tables in my Select Query

My Query:

```
SELECT Group_Concat(tp.EMPCODE), tp.DEPARTMENT, Group_Concat(d.dte) Absentddate, COUNT(tp.EMPCODE) Totalnoofabsentdates
FROM test_prefixmaster tp
JOIN daterange30 d
LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode) AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
GROUP BY tp.EMPCODE;
```

Afetr Execution of My Query the below is the result:

```
 EmpId                 Absent_dates                   Total_no_of_Absent_days
    1101                  2012-12-02                            1
    1102,1102          2012-12-02,2012-12-03                    2
    1104,1104,1104     2012-12-02,2012-12-03,2012-12-04         3
```

But my Actual Requirement is to display the results like below:

```
EmpId        Absent_dates            Total_no_of_Absent_days
1101          2012-12-02                     1
1102          2012-12-02
1102          2012-12-03                     2
1104          2012-12-02
1104          2012-12-03
1104          2012-12-04                     3
```

Could any one what is the function need to use in MySQL?
thanks

Comment: Dont use group concat function it will return the same answer

Comment: Add your query to check this

Comment: better add your query and if u can in the sqlfiddle. you think we can guess your query or the query will come by magic ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT tp.EMPCODE, tp.DEPARTMENT, d.dte Absentddate, COUNT(tp.EMPCODE) Totalnoofabsentdates
   FROM test_prefixmaster tp
   JOIN daterange30 d
  LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode) AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
    WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
  ORDER BY tp.EMPCODE;
```

Comment: when i remove the Group_Concat() function from SQL Query I'm skipping with other records(I'm able to display the single record)I'm not displayed other record from string of records

Comment: can u give your example in sqlfiddle ?

Comment: look if you can modify here and put your table data. [test.demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb4dd/21) , i just filled it like that

Comment: Master Table Contains all Employee Records..
In Transaction Table The column PresentDate stores the Employee Present Date time,
That means Employee In Time and Out Time details....
If an Employee is absent then No Record will get Stored in Transaction table

Comment: I want to Display The Employee Absent Details for two Given Date Range,Like in My Question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tp.EMPCODE, tp.DEPARTMENT, d.dte, IFNULL(A.Totalnoofabsentdates , '') Totalnoofabsentdates
FROM test_prefixmaster tp 
JOIN daterange d
LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode) AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT tp.EMPCODE, d.dte Absentddate, COUNT(tp.EMPCODE) Totalnoofabsentdates
            FROM test_prefixmaster tp
            JOIN daterange1 d
            LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode) AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
            WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
            GROUP BY tp.EMPCODE) AS A ON tp.EMPCODE = A.EMPCODE AND d.dte = A.Absentddate;
```